# QTabBar scrollbar separation

Tags: c++, qt

I have a question and it seems that it has been asked before by someone else but with no answers since 2008.

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/17227-QTabBar-scrollbar-separation

Is it possible to separate the scrollbar from QTabBar like this?

```
"<-" tab1 | tab2 | tab3 | tab4 "->"
```

Comment: The documentation at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabbar.html only provides a method to control if they should be on the left or right side. I suspect you will have to implement it yourself if you want it to work that way.

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55097717/1378243 for a slightly smoother method.

Answer (score 1):

The scrollbars consists of two seperate QToolButton. I don't think they can be re-styled by subclassing QTabBar and overriding paintEvent. You will have to create your own function (with the help of paintEvent) that moves invisible tabs to the viewport. This is also the same way how Qt has implemented it see [makeVisible](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qtabbar.cpp.html#_ZN14QTabBarPrivate11makeVisibleEi) and connect seperate buttons to it which moves the tabs.

There is also another **easy way** to connect your own buttons to QTabBar. At first you have to call

```
setUsesScrollButtons(bool useButtons)
```

and set this value to true. Then you re-style the scrollbar with an alpha channel, so it becomes invisible.

```
QTabBar QToolButton {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border:0;
}

QTabBar QToolButton::right-arrow:enabled {   
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border:0;
}

QTabBar QToolButton::right-arrow:disabled {
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
   border:0;
}

QTabBar QToolButton::left-arrow:enabled {  
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border:0;
}

QTabBar QToolButton::left-arrow:disabled {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border:0;
}
```

Then you can create two QPushButton or QToolButton with `<` and `>`.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
     ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(ui->tabWidget->currentIndex()+1);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
     ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(ui->tabWidget->currentIndex()-1);
}
```

Sample screen

[image: QTabBar]

Maybe that's enough for your use and you don't need to re-implement all the stuff, which will take a couple of days probably.

If you want to have the QPushButton or QToolButton inside QTabBar you can archieve this by subclassing paintEvent. To do so, set the QPushButton or QToolButton to the QTabBar parent and add to the x-coordinate the size of the QPushButton, so they don't overlap. (screenshot has the buttons not as parent.)